# .htaccess - reescrevendo URL não-amigável

Tags: apache, url

Quando eu faço a requisição :

```
http://localhost/project/mycontroller/
```

a URL reescreve pra

```
http://localhost/project/mycontroller/?l=mycontroller
```

Ou seja, além do `/mycontroller` o .htaccess (suponho) está concatenando na url  o mesmo parâmetros de `GET` só que na forma não amigável.

Nota 1 : `l`  é minha variável do `$_GET` mesmo e tudo funciona perfeitamente, mesmo se eu zoar com a URL não-amigável.

Nota 2 : Primeiramente pensei que fosse um redirecionamento, mas coloquei um `exit()` na primeira linha do index  e mesmo assim a URL continuou reescrevendo a parte não-amigável.

Como resolver isso?

**.htaccess**

```
<Files magic>
ForceType application/x-httpd-php5
</Files>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On 
Header append Vary User-Agent       

#?l=local -> /local
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9_]+)$ ?l=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9_]+)/$ ?l=$1 [NC,L]

#?l=local&sl=sublocal -> local/sublocal
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9_]+)/([a-z0-9_]+)$ ?l=$1&sl=$2 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9_]+)/([a-z0-9_]+)/$ ?l=$1&sl=$2 [NC,L]

#?l=local&sl=sublocal&cod=1 -> local/sublocal-1
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9_]+)/([a-z0-9_]+)/([0-9]+)$ ?l=$1&sl=$2&cod=$3 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9_]+)/([a-z0-9_]+)/([0-9]+)/$ ?l=$1&sl=$2&cod=$3 [NC,L]

#?l=local&sl=sublocal&cod=1 -> local/sublocal/var
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9_]+)/([a-z0-9_]+)/([a-z0-9]+)$ ?l=$1&sl=$2&var=$3 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9_]+)/([a-z0-9_]+)/([a-z0-9]+)/$ ?l=$1&sl=$2&var=$3 [NC,L]

</IfModule>
```

Comment: Bem vindo a Stack Overflow em português! sugiro que leia o tópico [Como fazer uma boa pergunta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)... No momento não é possível entender qual a sua duvida, sugiro que edite a pergunta e deixe mais claro o que você deseja fazer e o quê não está conseguindo

Comment: É, eu troquei "alguém já resolveu" por "como resolver", mas o Rodrigo tem razão. Por favor, [edite](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/27735/edit) a pergunta para esclarecer qual é o exato problema.

Comment: Opa, gente ! Valeu, vou tentar explicar melhor.. hehe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

De uma forma mais geral, já que não se sabe o que você pretende nem como vai usar o seu .htaccess, para obter a query string "l", bastaria isso nele:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?l=$1
```

Ao chamar o endereço indicado na pergunta, você receberia "mycontroller/" armazenada em $_GET['l']. Deste modo, você também pode passar algo como:

```
seu_dominio/project/mycontroller/segundo_parametro/terceiro_parametro/
```

o que retornaria:

```
mycontroller/segundo_parametro/terceiro_parametro/
```

Bastando tratar a string para separar os dados. Por exemplo, no PHP:

```
$qs = explode("/", $_GET['l']);
```

que seria:

```
Array (
    [0] => my_controller
    [1] => segundo_parametro
    [2] => terceiro_parametro
    [3] => 
)
```

Comment: Faltavam essas duas diretivas de RewriteCond,  e hoje mesmo eu tava pensando em parar de fazer regras específicas pra uma geral ! Seu comentário caiu como uma luva ! Obrigado @Blau  !

Comment: esse .htaccess funcionou pra tudo que vai direto pro /index.php, porém, quando chamo um controller de uma página existente ele falha, manda eu pro sistema de arquivos da pasta, imagina o que pode ser?

Comment: @rcBytes, será um prazer tentar ajudar, mas não podemos fazer isso nos comentários. Fique à vontade para abrir uma nova pergunta detalhando o problema. Assim mais opiniões poderão vir, com uma grande possibilidade de abranger mais casos de uso das regras do .htaccess.